# Why doesn't bridged networking work on VMware Server 2.0 w/ Ubuntu 9.04?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vmware-server

I'm installing VMware Server 2.0 on an Ubuntu 9.04 system. I have an Ubuntu 9.04 guest with Bridged network interface configured.

When I try to get an address during installation, the guest fails to contact the DHCP server. NAT and Host-only networking both work fine, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question, as the information is located in two places and not easily searchable, hopefully this helps someone else.

The problem is that the VSOCK module isn't getting compiled, despite gcc, binutils and the kernel source packages all being present.

```
ii  binutils                                  2.19.1-0ubuntu3                    The GNU assembler, linker and binary utiliti
ii  gcc                                       4:4.3.3-1ubuntu1                   The GNU C compiler
ii  linux-headers-2.6.28-11                   2.6.28-11.42                       Header files related to Linux kernel version
ii  linux-headers-2.6.28-11-server            2.6.28-11.42                       Linux kernel headers for version 2.6.28 on x
ii  linux-image-2.6.28-11-server              2.6.28-11.42                       Linux kernel image for version 2.6.28 on x86
ii  linux-source-2.6.28                       2.6.28-11.42                       Linux kernel source for version 2.6.28 with
```

There is actually a [bug filed on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vmware-server/+bug/294978) about this issue, and a user submitted a patch to a similar query on Ubuntu Forums. Patching the [vmware-config.pl as described](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=6267637&postcount=17) worked for me. Here's the patch:

```
--- /usr/bin/vmware-config.pl.orig  2008-11-28 12:06:35.641054086 +0100
+++ /usr/bin/vmware-config.pl   2008-11-28 12:30:38.593304082 +0100
@@ -4121,6 +4121,11 @@
     return 'no';
   }

+  if ($name eq 'vsock') {
+    print wrap("VMWare config patch VSOCK!\n");
+    system(shell_string($gHelper{'mv'}) . ' -vi ' . shell_string($build_dir . '/../Module.symvers') . ' ' . shell_string($build_dir . '/vsock-only/' ));
+  }
+
   print wrap('Building the ' . $name . ' module.' . "\n\n", 0);
   if (system(shell_string($gHelper{'make'}) . ' -C '
              . shell_string($build_dir . '/' . $name . '-only')
@@ -4143,6 +4148,10 @@
     if (try_module($name, $build_dir . '/' . $name . '.o', 0, 1)) {
       print wrap('The ' . $name . ' module loads perfectly into the running kernel.'
                  . "\n\n", 0);
+      if ($name eq 'vmci') {
+   print wrap("VMWare config patch VMCI!\n");
+   system(shell_string($gHelper{'cp'}) . ' -vi ' . shell_string($build_dir.'/vmci-only/Module.symvers') . ' ' . shell_string($build_dir . '/../'));
+      } 
       remove_tmp_dir($build_dir);
       return 'yes';
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually get the bridged networking working? I just installed 2.0.1 on jaunty (2.6.28-11) and it doesn't appear to be working.

Help!

Comment: Follow the link to the bug on Launchpad and patch the vmware-config.pl script as described. I'll embellish my answer with the patch.

Answer (score 0):

I guess my question was more regarding 2.0.1, I tried the patch but it bridged networking still doesnt appear to be working. What would be a good test? I just create a VM with a ubuntu server 9.04 iso and see if it can pull an ip from DHCP... when it cant I think that bridged networking is not working.

Should I download server 2.0.0 and try this?

Comment: I'm using VMware server 2.0.1, Build 156745.

Comment: Maybe I am testing it wrong... It would be really great to get some help!

I have seen issues where people dont have settings in their host correct for the bridged networking to work.

Comment: I am in the #vmware channel on irc.ubuntu.net, trying to get some help from them... Some people say it works no problem out of box...

Comment: Doing a fresh install of 9.04, hoping this will work.